# Skins / Themes for Soundmanager 2

Tags: javascript, html, audio, soundmanager2

I am currently considering to use Soundmanager2 as an audio player for a small project. I like SM2 a lot, but unfortunately I can't find an implementation that provides an inline player with basic controls (play, pause, progress bar, time, volume control).

The only thing I found is the [basic player](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/play-mp3-links/basic.html).
[image: Soundmanager 2 - Basic]

Does anyone of you know a way to use Soundmanager2 with a classic control interface ([like this](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2557221/online/demos/jplayer-black-and-yellow/index.html))?

[image: jPlayer demo]

Comment: Not sure it helps but it shouldn't be too hard to port your exemple to SoundManager considering it's already html/css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some casual research, I found out that Soundmanager 2 is far too powerful and complex for just creating an html5 player. I decided to use [jMediaelement](https://github.com/aFarkas/jMediaelement/tree/master) instead, a very flexible audio / video development kit with a focus on website players with a classic control interface.

Answer (score 0):

According to a discussion at Soundmanager's site at  https://getsatisfaction.com/schillmania/topics/track_list_with_controls_prev_next_button

Here's the lowdown:

---

add:

`pagePlayer.playNext()` 
`pagePlayer.playPrevious()`

Just make the necessary buttons with HTML/CSS. Inside those buttons use the onclick attribute, for example:
    open tag: a onclick="pagePlayer.playNext()" close tag

Do not use an "href" attribute. That will execute the javascript method when clicked.

---

Also, people on this site are working with volume for soundmanager2's player. Search "volume change soundmanager." Here's one guys: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625500/strange-issue-setting-volume-on-my-music-player-soundmanager](https://getsatisfaction.com/schillmania/topics/track_list_with_controls_prev_next_button)

```
// set base volume
$('header .volume-slider').each(function() {
  var slider = $('.slider', this);
  var volume = slider.data('volume');

  console.log('Initial volume: '+volume);
  $('.slider', this).height(volume/2);
});

// play / pause track
var sound;
$(document).on('click', '#snippets .tracks li', function() {
  var li = $(this);
  console.log('Creating new sound with volume: '+$('header .volume-slider .slider').data('volume'));

  sound = soundManager.createSound({
    id: li.data('id'),
    url: li.data('stream')+'?consumer_key=' + 'htuiRd1JP11Ww0X72T1C3g',
    volume: $('header .volume-slider .slider').data('volume')
  });
});

// change volume
$('header .volume-slider').mouseup(function(e) {
  var pos = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top;
  var slider = $('.slider', this);

  slider.data('volume', (100-(pos*2)));
  var volume = slider.data('volume');

  slider.height(volume/2);

  if (sound) {
    console.log('Setting volume: '+volume);
    sound.setVolume(volume);
  }
});
```

---

So, does it follow that if you can set nex/prev and make a button for it, could you come up with a volume change and then style a bar for it?